# How can "width" of git --stat be configured

Tags: git

The default maximum width of the `--stat` output produced by git is 80 characters if you use a non-normal terminal (IntelliJ in my case). From the [doc](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---statltwidthgtltname-widthgtltcountgt):

```
Maximum width defaults to terminal width, or 80 columns if not connected to a
terminal, and can be overridden by <width>.
```

This can be changed by giving an `width` value if you need wider or narrower output.

**Question:**
Is there a way to set this `width`-value by configuring it in git, give it through some environment var or some other way? It's annoying to have to write it every time I need it.

This option is used in multiple places, here is some but I guess there is more that I do not know of:

```
git diff --stat=200
git log --stat=200
git show --stat=200
git stash show --stat=200
```

---

Edit

Try setting the width to something small (`--stat=15`) and you will see the path get left-truncated to `...`. This is not what I want! I need the full path to be visible.

Note that `diff.statGraphWidth` is not an option since that only changes the amount of space occupied by the stat-graph-part of the line. That is the `25 ++-` part of this line:

```
.../myfile.ts | 25 ++-
```

I would like to see the full path to be visible by default, something like so:

```
project/some/reallylong/and/huge/pathintothetreesomewhere/src/myfile.ts | 25 ++-
```

Comment: No I do not want it to be truncated! But the default 80 is to small for the long and deep path's in the project I'm in. The note about 15 is just something you could try to get a feel for what I'm talking about.

Comment: Yes, and that is what the question is all about! Could I configure that value somewhere so that I do not need to write `--stat=200` every time I need it?

Comment: Okay, sorry. Now I see that the `diff.statGraphWidth` setting corresponds to the `--stat-graph-width` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `COLUMNS` environment variable to have git squish or expand its width for `--stat`.

This environment variable is normally used to specify the terminal width, and git uses it to calculate how wide it should make its stat `+++--` rows and how to trim the filename.

Some combination of `COLUMNS` and config `diff.statGraphWidth` should get you what you need.

```bash
COLUMNS=30 git -c diff.statGraphWidth=5 diff --stat
```

### Just what is `COLUMNS`?

From the `bash` man page:

> #### Shell Variables
>
> `COLUMNS` -
> Used by the `select` compound command to determine the terminal width when printing selection lists. Automatically set if the `checkwinsize` option is enabled or in an interactive shell upon receipt of a `SIGWINCH`.

The `COLUMNS` environment variable is normally set automatically by Bash when the terminal size is changed (technically Bash receives a `SIGWINCH` from `xterm` provided `xterm` is behaving). If it's not being updated, check `shopt checkwinsize` is ON. If it's not on, try adding `shopt -s checkwinsize` to your `~/.bashrc` and logging in again.

You can also set it manually using `COLUMNS=$(tput cols)` as a workaround.

Comment: Solved my usecase by adding this alias: **alias git='COLUMNS=`tput cols` git'**

Comment: @UlfR `COLUMNS` *should* always equal the output from `tput cols`, perhaps `checkwinsize` is off. In Bash, `shopt checkwinsize` should be on by default. If it's not, try (instead of my hack) adding `shopt -s checkwinsize` to your `.bashrc`.

Comment: Hmm, strange. `checkwinsize` is on, `COLUMNS` is set and updated automatically when window is resized. But `git` does not seem to care about that. It only respect `COLUMNS` when it prepends the command as in your example. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Git 2.43 (Q4 2023) adds another option, in addition of `COLUMNS=30`: "[`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0b493d2986ab2664a35a87db04154c795f74d3fd/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> learned `diff.statNameWidth` configuration variable, to give the default width for the name part in the "`--stat`" output.

See [commit bd48adc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd48adc31d0522e7877aa494ce7df91581e09587) (11 Sep 2023) by [Dragan Simic (`dragan-simic`)](https://github.com/dragan-simic).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0b493d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b493d2986ab2664a35a87db04154c795f74d3fd), 29 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`diff --stat`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd48adc31d0522e7877aa494ce7df91581e09587): add config option to limit filename width
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Dragan Simic</sup>

> Add new configuration option `diff.statNameWidth=<width>` that is equivalent to the command-line option `--stat-name-width=<width>`, but it is ignored by format-patch.
> This follows the logic established by the already existing configuration option `diff.statGraphWidth=<width>`.
>
> Limiting the widths of names and graphs in the `--stat` output makes sense for interactive work on wide terminals with many columns, hence the support for these configuration options.
> They don't affect format-patch because it already adheres to the traditional 80-column standard.
>
> Update the documentation and add more tests to cover new configuration option `diff.statNameWidth=<width>`.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bd48adc31d0522e7877aa494ce7df91581e09587/Documentation/config/diff.txt#L55-L58):

> ### `diff.statNameWidth`
>
> Limit the width of the filename part in `--stat` output.
> If set, applies to all commands generating `--stat` output except format-patch.

`diff-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bd48adc31d0522e7877aa494ce7df91581e09587/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L207-L215):

> giving another width `<name-width>` after a comma or by setting
> `diff.statNameWidth=<width>`.
> The width of the graph part can be
> limited by using `--stat-graph-width=<width>` or by setting
> `diff.statGraphWidth=<width>`.
> Using `--stat` or
> `--stat-graph-width` affects all commands generating a stat graph,
> while setting `diff.statNameWidth` or `diff.statGraphWidth`
> does not affect `git format-patch`.
> By giving a third parameter `<count>`, you can limit the output to
> the first `<count>` lines, followed by `...` if there are more.